# Algorithm mistake, finding areas between lines

Tags: java, algorithm, calculus

I was doing my math hw, and it required me to calculate areas between 2 lines. I solved couple of them, I got them right(its online so it shows me whether i got it wrong or right), then I thought about writing a program that does the calculation for me, I created a nice algorithm, used java for the program, but in the end it didn't give me the right answer.
I put the data from one of the questions I already solved whether i got it right or wrong.

Can you please tell me the mistake in the algorithm??

```
public class DailyHelper {

public static double f(double x) {
    double y = 5*x;
    return y;
}

public static double g(double x) {
    double y= 4*x*x;
    return y;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double xLower = 0;
    double xHigher = 5/4;
    double areaF=0;
    double areaG=0;
    double change = (xHigher-xLower)/100000;
    for(double k=xLower; k<xHigher; k=k+change) {
        areaF = areaF+(change*f(k));
    }

    for(double k=xLower; k<xHigher; k=k+change) {
        areaG = areaG+(change*g(k));
    }
    double area = areaF-areaG;
    System.out.println(area);
}
}
```

Comment: area between two lines? Can you please explain?

Comment: We should know what the algorithm is supposed to do first. *Compute an area between two lines* is a pretty vague description of what it should do, and I don't see any concept of "line" in the code. No comment at all either. Naming methods "f" and "g" doesn't help in understanding what they're supposed to do either.

Comment: I suppose you're trying to perform integration of two functions in order to find the area below function?

Comment: yes, basically you find the area under each line and subtract them. To do this you take the integral of the lines between two points, in this case x=0 and x=5/4 which would give you the area. In my code, i tried to divide the area under each function into 100000 rectangles so that the overestimate or underestimate would be close to the real area. then i subtracted these two areas. which in my opinion was supposed to give the same answer with the integral way.

Comment: "vague description"?? i gave you an upper limit and a lower limit, and two functions, and said the area between? how hard it is to understand?

Comment: You said "area between **lines**". What you have is the area between two functions, of which *only one* is a line.

Comment: i didn't say STRAIGHT LINES, and you can clearly see the function 4*x*x

Comment: one of the  function is not LINEAR - its a parabola .. so how can u divide it in squares ?

Comment: go take calculus class. i dont wana explain to you how to divide a function into infinite rectangles

Comment: @user2864414: how about you going to a programming class? You're the one asking for help, with a poor description of a problem, and crappy code. If you're so smart and too lazy to name your variables and methods correctly and to explain what you want to do, then don't ask for help. Or at least be polite.

Comment: you are 100% right, and I seriously apologize to you for not being polite. I should have made my question more clear, and not have been rude to people who tried to help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a quick thought.
Your `xHigher` variable is always 1, since you're dividing `int` by `int`. Try `5/4d`

Comment: or just `double xHigher = 1.25`

Comment: @user14325 yeah, it's also correct. I just pointed out the exact mistake he made :)

Answer (score 0):

If there are 2 straight random lines and you want to calculate area from vertical lines L1 and L2, L1 < L2, then you must construct that trapezoid (by finding the corner coordinates) and calculate the area. However this doesn't work on non-linear "lines", you'll need to follow a rule like that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#Methods_for_one-dimensional_integrals